# Where could one find the source attachments for Glassfish?

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, glassfish

In my current project we use Glassfish, so we have org.glassfish.extras.glassfish-embedded-all-3.1.1.jar as a Maven dependency. This is all right so far, until I try to fetch the sources or the Javadoc for anything inside it using Eclipse.

As for the official Glassfish pages, both the [Maven repo](https://maven.java.net/content/repositories/releases/org/glassfish/main/extras/glassfish-embedded-all/3.1.2/) and the [Java download page](http://download.java.net/maven/glassfish/org/glassfish/extras/glassfish-embedded-all/3.1.1/) holds only empty jars (2KB) as source attachments.

I have managed to find the [SVN repo](https://svn.java.net/svn/glassfish~svn/tags/3.1.1/) for the project, but I can't help wondering why wouldn't there be valid and usable source jars in the official locations? What would be the canonical solution for this problem?

Answer (score 0):

For study GlassFish purpose, let's read this tutorial:
Import from GlassFish project SVN to your prefer IDE:

```
https://svn.java.net/svn/glassfish~svn/
```

https://blogs.oracle.com/geertjan/entry/how_to_set_up_glassfish1

and result:

[image]

(Image credit: blogs.oracle.com )

Comment: I might have not be clear enough. What I wish is to be able to hover over (in Eclipse) the components (for example javax.persistence.PersistenceContext) contained in the glassfish-embedded-all-3.1.1.jar dependency and have their sources and javadoc available. As of now, I only see "This element has no attached Javadoc ..." when hovering over an item and "The source attachment does not contain the source for the file [...]" when trying to inspect its source. The SVN repo linked by you (and mentioned by me) does not have all the sources and can't be set as source attachment.

Comment: This is not a proper answer! When trying to config the svn you indicate, it says it has been moved to some other url, which now requires a certificate to access. The main question is valid: why there are no sources in the dedicate jar file?